# Google cloud rolling update error Required 'Alpha Access' permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use google cloud rolling update but it is showing error as 
**ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.instance-groups.managed.rolling-action.start-update) Could not fetch resource:
 - Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'.**
i dont know how to allow my project access to this feture.

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google cloud compute alpha features are only enabled for whitelisted projects.

You can go to corresponding products page, in this case:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups,

click on `Request to be whitelisted to use this feature` to request access for your project.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I will try it and accept the answer.

Comment: There is no such link to get whitelisted on mentioned link. Please help.

Comment: Hmm... when I click on above mentioned link, first blue box with "star Alpha" has: "[Request to be whitelisted to use this feature](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScHTn-gmhtGVwWrsG4sEbcdOmhnc6OUn_xbthPtaLP_0JvLMg/viewform)".

Answer (score 2):

Update for the original question.  This feature is no longer in alpha so there is no need to white list your project or use the alpha gcloud command. Please see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups) for the gcloud cli syntax.